# Threadsafe way to convert time between timezones

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

I am writing a application to convert utc-time to different timezones, now I can use something like this

```
putenv("TZ=TIMEZONE1"); 
tzset()
...
do time conversions
```

but I don't think it is thread safe, so is there any C/C++ library which can do timezone conversion by taking timezone as argument to function instead of being some global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/date_time/doc/index.html) supports time-zone conversions.

Comment: I have never used boost, so can I just include Boost datetime?

Comment: ok that was easy `sudo apt-get install libboost-date-time1.40-dev` and I am ready to go!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does Boost have its own timezone database or somehow use the system one?

Comment: I thought the concern was thread safety.  Is boost datetime safe w/o taking additional measures?  AFAIK most boost modules are not.

Comment: That's a good question. Also note that wrapping the call with locks does not make it thread-safe, since modifying the environment is dangerous if any other thread could be accessing the environment at all.

Comment: hmm that is a very good question, looks like datetime may not be thread safe, it may internally still use same tzset functions, http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2005/03/82339.php ... time to read the source

Comment: @R.. boost does use its own timezone database, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.tz_database

Comment: @Duck: Where you took this info from? Boost is thread safe in the 'normal' sense: you can use it from multiple threads as long as you operate on different objects. This is the case here.

Comment: @Anurag: I'm sure it doesn't use tzset because it uses it's own implementation in order to be portable to other platforms that don't have tzset.

Comment: @ybungalobill: you seem to be right I couldn't find any specific on the contrary, and as I would not be sharing objects I think it is perfectly ok for me , thanks

Comment: Not really. It can only use the system local timezone, or user supplied timezone definitions. Which is rather useless and one can do that with the plain old C time API. If it could read Olson timezone database then it would be really useful.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: plainly false. It has [its own database format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#tz_database_datafile) that it can read, with the database distributed at `libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv`. Also you can extend it to support other format.

Comment: @ybungalobill that database is not up-to-date and is less than useful: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/235828

Answer (score 3):

You probably need your own code/library capable of handling time zones. The standard library's handling is very backwards and not suitable for working with anything more complex than a single timezone that's fixed for the lifetime of the program.

One possible solution, though, would be to allocate shared memory, `fork`, and change the timezone in the child process, then pass the result back via shared memory to be read after `waitpid` returns in the parent. This is mildly expensive, but not as bad as it sounds, since `fork` is fast on modern systems. My experience is that 1 `fork` equals 2-3 `pthread_create` calls, and 1 `pthread_create` call equals 2-3 `open` calls. Since changing timezones will require opening one or more files and performing IO on them, you probably won't be increasing the total time cost by more than a factor of 3-5 times. If you could keep around a child process for each timezone you're working with, it could be more efficient, of course.

Comment: +1 for confirming, i was hoping there must be something in libc etc, so looks like a process to sort data into timezones, and then separate process for each timezone is the way to go :(